# React Webpack bundler does not recompile on file change

Tags: reactjs, webpack

When running webpack with the watch command, my webpack seems to 'give up' after a while when i change a file. Only the first update to my file causes a recompile. Consecutive modifications do not.

my folder structure:

[image]

my **package.json**:

```
{
  "name": "MVCReact",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "./wwwroot/src/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev:bundler": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack -w"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/node": "^7.12.6",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.7",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.12.7",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.1",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "webpack": "^5.6.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.2",
    "eslint": "^7.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.21.5",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.2.0"
  }
}
```

my **.eslintrc.js**:

```
module.exports = {
    parser: 'babel-eslint',
    env: {
    browser: true,
    commonjs: true,
    es6: true,
    node: true,
    jest: true,
    },
    parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 2020,
    ecmaFeatures: {
        impliedStrict: true,
        jsx: true,
    },
    sourceType: 'module',
    },
    plugins: ['react', 'react-hooks'],
    extends: [
    'eslint:recommended',
    'plugin:react/recommended',
    'plugin:react-hooks/recommended',
    ],
    settings: {
    react: {
        version: 'detect',
    },
    },
    rules: {
    },
};
```

My **babel.config.js**:

```
module.exports = {
    presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react'],
};
```

My **webpack.config.js**:

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        index: "./wwwroot/src/index.js"
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "./wwwroot/dist"),
        filename: "[name].js"
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader"
                },
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

my **index.js**:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import App from './components/App';

ReactDOM.hydrate(
<App />,
document.getElementById('root'),
);
```

My **app.js** (the file I'm modifying):

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export default function App() {
const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
return (
    <div>
    <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 3)}>{count}</button>
    </div>
);
}
```

I run the `dev:bundler` script from my **package.json**. When it launches it rebuilds the webpack. When the **app.js** file is modified for the first time, I see the following message in the terminal log:
[image]
Any consecutive modifications to the **app.js** file do not regenerate the code. I can empty the whole **app,js** file and nothing gets updated. A modification is still registered, and webpack still compiles, just not with the latest file. I see this in the terminal log:

[image]

Can anyone explain what's going on and how and how I fix this?

UPDATE:

1. I attempted to use the cross-env package, but it leads to the same result.
2. A link to the project in github: [sample project](https://github.com/whitehair30/sampleproject261120)

Comment: My first guess is that you need to use something like the 'cross-env' package
https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env.

Comment: I implemented this and the issue remained unchanged

Comment: Do you have a working example?

Comment: I just added a link to project repository

Comment: off topic, but I would just stick to options like next.js for server side rendering than to spending fixing up own boilerplate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I pulled your code and I found you should replace the line below

```
import App from './components/App';
```

by

```
import App from './components/app';
```

and it will works

Comment: I created a pull request in github repository https://github.com/whitehair30/sampleproject261120/pull/1

Comment: thanks, I was going crazy :D